# How to hide an application based on the NetBeans Platform?

Tags: user-interface, netbeans, show-hide

I'm not referring to a GUI-less application. I'm trying to have an application based on the NetBeans platform as a System Tray application. I was able to do the System Tray part quite easy but I'm having issues trying to figure out how to Hide/Show the GUI. I'll keep looking in the API meanwhile.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WindowManager.getDefault().getMainWindow().setVisible(true/false) should work to hide and show the entire GUI, unless it has multiple windows (pure Swing Frame.getFrames() should give you all JFrame based windows, if that helps).

Not sure if that will solve the problem if you want the main window hidden on *startup* (but if it is a very simple UI, as is true of many tray apps, you might be able to just work with a dead-simple implementation of WindowManager such as WindowManager.Trivial and leave out the standard NetBeans windowing system entirely).

Comment: Believe it or not I was getting into the question to answer it myself with the same answer as I just found that out in the API documentation.